# DeprecationWarning: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

Tags: django, django-userena

I'm using Django 1.6 and Userena.  My project appears to be working fine, but I keep seeing the following pop up in my terminal.

```
DeprecationWarning: The use of AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to define user profiles has been deprecated.
profile = user.get_profile()
```

I'm worried what this means or what future problems this may cause.  Is there a way to fix it?